# Tuning vs switching vs turning a radio / TV channel onto a particular chnnel

Tags: verbs

Which one of the follwoing sentences sound more natural to you:

> - Can you **tune** the radio onto BBC?
> - Can you **switch** the radio onto BBC?
> - Can you **turn** the radio onto BBC?

Also, please tell me about a TV channel. I know the verb switch is mostly used in this case, but I need to know whether it is possible to use 'tuning' or 'turning' for a TV channel too; for instance:

> - Please switch to channel 9.

Can we substitute 'switch' with one of the other two above-mentioned verbs?

Comment: You "switch **to** a channel or frequency." If you turned the radio, you'd be moving the radio itself, not changing its frequency.

Comment: @MorganFR so you mentioned that I have to reword my sentence like this: "Can you switch to channel BBC?". Sound all right. But what about a TV channel?

Comment: "Switching to a channel" on TV is alright. On the radio/TV, you might also use "tune in" http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tune+in, especially on a program or something specific, not a channel in general.

Comment: @MorganFR , but what about "turning" to a TV channel; does it sound natural in AE?

Comment: Turning the TV/radio **to** a channel/frequency is also widely used.

Comment: @MorganFR please make your answers a post. :)

Comment: Should be "**the** BBC".

Answer (score 1):

In each case, it would be best to use "to" instead of "onto":

> Can you tune the radio to BBC?
>   Can you switch the radio to BBC?
>   Can you turn the radio to BBC?

This is because "onto" expresses movement to a surface ("move *onto* the pavement") whereas "to" can express movement towards a condition or state (in this case, the state is the radio receiving BBC).

You could use any of these, but *tune* is the most commonly used. It is acceptable to use *turn* and *switch*, but less common. I expect *turn* will become increasingly less common as more and more people move from analogue radios to digital ones, as *turn* refers to turning the tuning wheel/knob on the radio to a particular frequency.

---

For the second part of your question, it is acceptable to "tune" a TV to a particular channel. However, I would again expect this to become less common as analogue televisions become a thing of the past.

It is correct and common to say "turn the TV to channel 9."

---

Keep in mind that relative usages of the terms can and do vary greatly with region. I would not be surprised to hear any of the combinations mentioned in your question, but some regions may use one more than the others.

Comment: Thank you very much LMS; as usual a an informative answer. But let me asking one more question close this thread for myself; Do you agree that both the "turning" and "switching" to a specific TV channel would sound idiomatic and natural?

Comment: @A-friend: Both of those sound natural. You may also want to consider "switch (the TV) over to (a channel)," which is used.